# A formula that seems to involve the variation coefficient

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics

A friend walking in Minsk, Belarus, found this mural from the Soviet period and sent me an image (see below) of it, asking me what the formula in it was referring to. From my naive reading (which might be wrong!), I read this formula as
$$
C_v^k=\alpha\beta\sqrt{\frac{\sum \left(v^4-\frac{\sum v^4}{n}\right)^2}{(n-1)\left(\frac{\sum v^4}{n}\right)^2}}
$$
So it looks like some kind of variation coefficient, but there should be something more given these $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and these fourth powers of $v$.

A priori, it does not look like a purely mathematical formula. Given the theme of the mural, I think it should be related to some aspect of astrophysics or nuclear physics. However, I am not completely sure. So:

> Is this formula related to physics? If so, what is its meaning and what does it relate to?

Any help would be welcome.

> [image]